# Is it possible to invoke an OCaml Library from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ocaml

I'd like to know if there exists a way to invoke a library written in OCaml through NodeJS directly.

Comment: take a look at bucklescript i’d say

Comment: what exacly is it you want to do ?